# Phoenix Channel `push` ** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Jason.Encoder

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Whenever a user joins a channel, I want to send them a record of all the previous messages that were sent.

My implementation for `handle_info` below triggers this error `protocol Jason.Encoder not implemented for Hello.Messaging.Message`.

My guess is that `messages` is a list of structs, when it needs to be converted to a list of maps?

```
  use Phoenix.Channel
  alias Hello.Messaging

  def join("room:" <> room_id, params, socket) do
    send(self(), {:after_join, params})
    {:ok, assign(socket, :room_id, room_id)}
  end

  # push triggers the error message here
  def handle_info({:after_join, _params}, socket) do
    messages = Messaging.list_messages()
    push(socket, "messages", %{messages: messages})
    {:noreply, socket}
  end

  def handle_in("new_msg", %{"body" => body}, socket) do
    case Messaging.create_message(%{body: body, room_id: socket.assigns.room_id}) do
      {:ok, msg} ->
        broadcast!(socket, "new_msg", %{body: msg.body})
        {:noreply, socket}

      {:error, reason} ->
        {:error, reason}
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Jason.Encoder`](https://hexdocs.pm/jason/Jason.Encoder.html#content) is not implemented for structs, and your `Hello.Messaging.Message` is a struct.

If you own the struct, enable encoding for it as [described in the documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/jason/readme.html)

```elixir
@derive {Jason.Encoder, only: [....]}
defstruct # ...
```

If you cannot modify the struct, convert it to map with [`Map.from_struct/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#from_struct/1).

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing my own answer here.

The problem is that `messages` from `Message.list_messages()` is a list of structs, when `push` takes either a `map` or `tagged {:binary, data} tuple`.

Converting `messages` into a `map` was the solution:

```
map_messages = Enum.map(struct_messages, fn s_msg -> Map.take(s_msg, [:id, :body]) end)
```

Comment: Deriving the protocol implementation as shown in my answer would be a _proper_ solution if you own the struct.